# VBA: Looping through column with dynamic data set and deleting specific text from each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem;

I am tying to create a macro that will run through a column in a sheet, in this case column A, and loop through each cell containing data. Whenever the macro loops through a cell, I need it to delete a specific set of text from each cell. This text I need to delete will never change as the data is the same from a website I pull from. However the text I need to delete will always be followed by a string of numbers, which in this case represents incoming freight orders to the facility where I work.

Example of data:

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRSuJ.png)

I tried creating a macro that will leave the numbers but delete {"isaId": specifically. I need the numbers by themselves to copy into an HTML send request in another part of the tool I am making.

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim test As Worksheet
        Set test = Worksheets("test")
    Dim testcheck As Boolean
    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If testcheck = "27*703" Like "276782703" = True Then

'   276782703 is just an example number; the numbers will always be in this format, meaning they will always start with 2 and end with 703 with five random numbers in-between.

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = testcheck
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I think I may be using wildcards incorrectly, though I am not sure, and the code I have gives me an error, so I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your code have to do with removing `{"isaId":` ?

Comment: Sorry, I may have worded my question incorrectly. I am approaching it as looking for "2" with 5 random numbers and "703," and when found, replace the entire value of the cell with just the number found in the cell. Hopefully that makes sense. I have not had to do this before so I am not even sure if I am wording my question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this basic Regular Expression (RegEx) matching.

```
Sub find2_____703()

    Dim i As Long, str As String
    Static rgx As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        rgx.Pattern = "2\d{5}703"
    End If

    With Worksheets("test")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            With rgx
                If .Test(str) Then
                    str = .Execute(str).Item(0)
                End If
            End With
            .Cells(i, "A") = str
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

The pattern is the number two, then exactly five random digits between zero and nine then seven-oh-three.